# discord.js v12 check if channel exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord.js

I'm coding my own ticket bot on discord.js. I need to check if guild have a channel (**by name**). Here's little piece of code:

```
if (userTickets.has(user.id) || reaction.message.guild.channels.cache.???(c => c.name === user.username.toLowerCase() + 's-ticket')) {
     user.send("You already have a ticket!");
     return;
}
```

**I tried the following:**

```
reaction.message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === user.username.toLowerCase() + 's-ticket')
reaction.message.guild.channels.cache.has(c => c.name === user.username.toLowerCase() + 's-ticket')
reaction.message.guild.channels.cache.has(user.username.toLowerCase() + 's-ticket')
```

But nothing helped

**SOLUTION:**
As suggested by [@Chiitoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13978851/chiitoi), in this case it is better to use `some()` function.
Also, `user.username` returns string with spaces and special characters, so you need to parse it.

This code works for me:

```
if (userTickets.has(user.id) || reaction.message.guild.channels.cache.some((channel) => channel.name === username.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/ig, "") + 's-ticket')) {
     user.send("You already have a ticket!");
     return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [some() method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=some) might be good here. And what does `user.username` return? I'm wondering if the returned value has any special or unique characters.

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH! Yes, *user.username* returned string that had special characters and spaces. So, the solution is like this: `reaction.message.guild.channels.cache.some((channel) => channel.name === username.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/ig, "") + 's-ticket')`